# Suppress chapter creation by BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, natbib

The title says it all really. I'm using the `rsc` bibliography style and placing the references will create the chapter heading "References".
Now I do want that gone since this is for a poster and the box/frame will hold "references".

In case a MWE is needed I supply one:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{rsc} %%basically loads natbib 

 \begin{document}

 \bibliographystyle{rsc}

 Some clever bloke came up with something\cite{cleverbloke2013}.

 \bibliography{somefile} 

 \end{document}
```

There must be a way, the natbib documentation is huge and I didn't find something fitting. Since I assume it is possible to change the title of the references it should be possible to change it to an empty title.

Comment: You should be able to do it with `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}` after `\usepackage{rsc}`

Comment: Are you sure that specifying the bibliography style `rsc` loads the `natbib` citation management package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}` after `\usepackage{rsc}`. See section 2.12 of the manual of `natbib`.

> The list of references normally appears as a `\section*` or `\chapter*`, depending on the main class. If one wants to redesign one’s own heading, say as a numbered section with `\section`, then `\bibsection` may be redefined by the user accordingly.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cleverbloke2013,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={1000},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rsc}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}

\begin{document}

Some clever bloke came up with something\cite{cleverbloke2013}.

\bibliographystyle{rsc}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to keep the example self contained; don't use it yourself, but `\bibliography{somefile}` (you know the real name).

[image]